# How can I create a snapshot of a curve in the Graph Editor (like Buffer Curve Snapshot feature in Maya)?

Tags: graph-editor, fcurves

Maya has something called Buffer Curve Snapshot in its graph editor which allows to temporarily save a snapshot of a curve and then use it as reference when doing further changes to the curve. You can also use it to try to preserve the curve after simplifying it to fewer keyframes. Does Blender have similar feature and if so how does one access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is called **Create Ghost Curves**

It will create a snapshot in dotted lines of the selected curve(s). That lime can then be used as reference.

For 2.8 Use the icon at the top of the curve editor.
[image]

To clear the ghost curve it just click on the X icon again on the same place where you created the curve.

For older versions of blender select the curve, press the space bar to acces the search menu and type ghost curves. Then you can enable or disable the function.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This feature is only present in Blender 2.8 and later right?

Comment: No it has been in blender for a while.

Comment: I'm almost sure it goes back to the 2.4 days...

Comment: Nice! It was very well hidden lol.